# Cálculo de diferença entre duas linhas SQL

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, query, soma

Tenho uma query pronta e gostaria de verificar a diferença entre duas colunas mas que isso seja feito por linha, criando uma nova coluna com o resultado. Preciso calcular a diferença Do ValorBase com o AjusteAcumulado e exibindo o resultado em uma nova coluna criada a direita. Código abaixo:

```
SELECT DISTINCT IOCORRENCIA.VALOROCORRENCIA,
       IOCORRENCIA.TIPO,

       CASE WHEN IOCORRENCIA.TIPO =70 THEN 'ACRÉSCIMO'
       WHEN IOCORRENCIA.TIPO = 2 THEN 'TRANSFERÊNCIA MONETÁRIA'
       WHEN IOCORRENCIA.TIPO = 90 THEN 'BAIXA PARCIAL'
       WHEN IOCORRENCIA.TIPO = 99 THEN 'BAIXA NO PERÍODO'
       ELSE ''END AS NONE_TIPO_OCORRENCIA,

       IOCORRENCIA.DATA,
       IOCORRENCIA.IDOCORRENCIA,

       CASE WHEN IOCORRENCIA.CONTABILIZAROCORRENCIA = 0  THEN 'NÃO CONTABILIZADO'
       WHEN IOCORRENCIA.CONTABILIZAROCORRENCIA = 1 THEN 'CONTABILIZADO'
       WHEN IOCORRENCIA.CONTABILIZAROCORRENCIA = 2  THEN 'PENDENTE DE CONTABILIZAÇÃO'
       ELSE '' END AS NOME_STATUS_CONTABILIZAÇÃO,

       IOCORRENCIA.CONTABILIZAROCORRENCIA,
       A.CODPATRIMONIO AS PATRIMONIO_ORIGEM,
       B.CODPATRIMONIO AS PATRIMONIO_DESTINO,
       A.DESCRICAO AS DESCRICAO_PAT_ORIGEM,
       B.DESCRICAO AS DESCRICAO_PAT_DESTINO,
       icalculorazao.depreciacaoacumulada AS DepAcumulada,
       icalculorazao.saldoresidual AS SaldoResidual,
       icalculorazao.ajustedepacumuladacorrigida AS AjusteAcumulado,
       icalculorazao.VALORBASE AS ValorBase

       
FROM IOCORRENCIA (NOLOCK) 

JOIN IPATRIMONIO A (NOLOCK)
ON (IOCORRENCIA.IDPATRIMONIOORIGEM=A.IDPATRIMONIO
AND IOCORRENCIA.CODCOLIGADA=A.CODCOLIGADA)

LEFT JOIN IPATRIMONIO B (NOLOCK)
ON (IOCORRENCIA.IDPATRIMONIODESTINO=B.IDPATRIMONIO
AND IOCORRENCIA.CODCOLIGADA=B.CODCOLIGADA) 

LEFT JOIN icalculorazao (NOLOCK)
ON icalculorazao.idocorrencia = iocorrencia.idocorrencia 


WHERE IOCORRENCIA.IDCENARIOCALCULO='1'
AND IOCORRENCIA.CODCOLIGADA='2'
AND IOCORRENCIA.DATA >= '01-01-2021'
AND IOCORRENCIA.DATA <= '12-30-2021' 

ORDER BY IOCORRENCIA.IDOCORRENCIA
```

Comment: icalculorazao.ajustedepacumuladacorrigida AS AjusteAcumulado,icalculorazao.VALORBASE AS ValorBase,  (icalculorazao.VALORBASE - icalculorazao.ajustedepacumuladacorrigida) AS diferenca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carlos, se for um calculo na mesma linha é o comentário acima, agora se queres por exemplo, agrupar esse calculo por algum campo, por exemplo o patrimônio agregador... dai terás que utilizar a soma com OVER e PARTITION BY.